# How can i keep the drawed rectangle on pictureBox according to selected index in listBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

On the left side in a listBox i have some items.
I want to do that when i click on an item draw rectangle click the button ConfirmRectangle it will remember that in this item i drawed already a rectangle.
So if i move to an item that i didn't draw yet rectangle there it will show the item as it is without any drawed rectangle. But if i click on any item that i already drawed rectangle before show the rectangle i drawed and also Enabled False the button ConfirmRectangle. Item without rectangle enabled true the button item with drawed rectangle enabled false.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace MinimizeCapture
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Rectangle RectClone;
        bool btn = false;
        Point RectStartPoint = Point.Empty;
        Point RectEndPoint = Point.Empty;
        private Brush selectionBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        private Pen pen;
        private string selectedIndex;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            btn = false;
            pen = new Pen(selectionBrush);
        }

        private void buttonSnap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.listBoxSnap.Items.Clear();
            this.pictureBoxSnap.Image = null;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void listBoxSnap_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowSnap snap = this.listBoxSnap.SelectedItem as WindowSnap;
            selectedIndex = this.listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex.ToString();
            this.pictureBoxSnap.Image = snap.Image;
        }

        private void checkBoxForceMDI_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowSnap.ForceMDICapturing = (sender as CheckBox).Checked;
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            listBoxSnap.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { this.listBoxSnap.Items.AddRange(WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).ToArray()); }));
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBoxSnap_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (pictureBoxSnap.Image != null)
            {
                {
                    Rectangle Rect = getRect(RectStartPoint, RectEndPoint);
                    RectClone = Rect;
                    if (Rect != Rectangle.Empty)
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Firebrick, Rect);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void pictureBoxSnap_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (btn == true)
            {
                RectEndPoint = e.Location;
                pictureBoxSnap.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        private void pictureBoxSnap_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            RectStartPoint = e.Location;
            btn = true;
        }

        private void pictureBoxSnap_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            btn = false;
            RectEndPoint = e.Location;
            pictureBoxSnap.Invalidate();
        }

        Rectangle getRect(Point p1, Point p2)
        {
            Point p = new Point(Math.Min(p1.X, p2.X), Math.Min(p1.Y, p2.Y));
            Size s = new Size(Math.Abs(p1.X - p2.X), Math.Abs(p1.Y - p2.Y));
            return new Rectangle(p, s);
        }

        private void ConfirmRectangle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ConfirmRectangle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            ConfirmRectangle.Enabled = false;
            StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\Settings.txt", true);
            w.WriteLine("Rectangle Location: " + RectClone.Location + " Rectangle Size: " + RectClone.Size + " Selected Index: " + selectedIndex);
            textBoxIndex.Text = selectedIndex.ToString();
            w.Close();
            listBoxSnap.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't tell us what the `WindowSnap` is you put into the ListBox; assuming it a class, can you expand it to include the rectangle?

Comment: The variable snap for exmaple when i click on an item contain this: {Window Text: maptest (Recovered) - Paint, Handle: 66764} the name of the item and the handle window. In fact in the listBox i have all the windows that currently open in the background if it's a program or a game and i take a screenshot of this windows and add them to the listBox and when i select an item in the listBox i see in the pictureBox the swcreenshot of the selected item(windows) . What i want to do is after drawing a rectangle on the current selected item(window) that it will remember the drawn rectangle.

Comment: And also i want it to take a screenshot next time from the rectangle i drawed in the window. And not to take a screenshot of all the window like now but only inside the drawn rectangle area.

Comment: This is the a link to the WindowSnap class it's a bit long but i don't think the class is needed to do what i want. It's all should be done in form1 i think. http://pastebin.com/GUJkmd81

Comment: In general i want to do two things: To remember items i drawed rectangle in them. When i click on items in the listBox those with drawed rectangle show the rectangle those without rectangle dont show anything if not drawed. And second thing to take a screenshot in items that they have rectangle inside only from the rectangle area.

Comment: But first thing is how to make it to remember/save the items that i drawed a rectangle already so when i click on the items those with rectangle inside will be saved/show and those who empty will keep be empty untill i draw inside them too.

Comment: The class is rather long; since you have it you could modify it but I think I would create a wrapper that holds one instance of that class and a rectangle and the bitmap inside the rectangle.. Who fills the list with the WindowSnap items? You would then fill it with that wrapper class instead..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a class you could use to fill your `ListBox` with, instead of the original `WindowSnap` class:

```
class SnapWrapper
{
    public WindowSnap windowSnap { get; set; }
    public Rectangle rect { get; set; }
    public Bitmap bitmap { get; set; }
    public SnapWrapper(WindowSnap windowSnap_) { windowSnap = windowSnap_; }
    public override string ToString() {  return windowSnap.ToString();  }
    public bool IsSet() { return rect != Rectangle.Empty; }
}
```

You would replace most of the `WindowSnap` references with `SnapWrapper.windowSnap`..

Now you can set the rectangle in the `SelectedItem`, maybe in an `OKButton_Click` event:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
   (listBox1.SelectedItem as SnapWrapper).rect = getRect(RectStartPoint, RectEndPoint);
```

using the getRect function from your previous question; or delete it again:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
    (listBox1.SelectedItem as SnapWrapper).rect = Rectangle.Empty;
```

and check it:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
   if ((listBox1.SelectedItem as SnapWrapper).IsSet() ) //do stuff...
```

How you can copy a portion from an image is easily googled; the `Graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, srceRect, unit)` format will do the job..

Comment: TaW there is no property IsSet() not exist. And second im getting error on  listBox1.SelectedItem as SnapWrapper Error 3 Cannot implicitly convert type 'MinimizeCapture.Form1.SnapWrapper' to 'bool'

Comment: `IsSet`is defined in the above `SnapWrapper` class. But my parenthesis got misplaced, see the edit!..